# Python not installing on Yosemite

Tags: python

I think I kinda made a mess here. I installed the 2.x version of Python for os x and then I realized that I needed to install the 3.x. So I downloaded the pkg for 3.x too and installed. While coding I realized that the terminal and everything was still using the 2.x version. So I looked in the internet a way to uninstall it and I ended up  for deleting some bin files which made the terminal not working. I repaired the permissions from Utility Disk, installed Python 3.x again, but no command for Python seems to be working. And no Python's file is added to the bin folder. Any help?

Comment: Talk with Apple support at this point?  It sounds like you've removed critical system functionality.  Just note:  you can install Python 2 and Python 3 side-by-side; they don't directly interfere with each other.

Comment: Generally you should never touch the standard Python install. That is, you should never remove it. Instead you should install your new versions using `homebrew`.

Comment: @Makoto But only Python's commands are not working, so I don't think I should call Apple support.

Comment: OS X uses Python for certain internal operations though. So if you've broken it then other things will break down the line.

Comment: @Ffisegydd the point is that after installing version 2 I installed version 3, but my system was still working on version 2. That's why the problem rised

Comment: @Ffisegydd hits it on the head: the OS is using Python 2.  If you've forcefully removed that link, then the best option is to talk with Apple to see how to get that repaired.  In the future, using a package manager to install it like Brew will help you tons in situations like this.

Comment: Yeah. Contact Apple. You say you've reinstalled Python 2 but are you absolutely sure you're installed it correctly? In the same place? What about any custom bits that Apple may have done to it? Symbolic links and such? Your best bet is to just restore things to as they should be by following Apple's advice. Then use http://brew.sh to install your own versions of Python. There's nothing we can really do to help you, other than give you this advice.

Comment: Install python as follows:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhutbLBKBok